# Помогите с задачей, цикл while

Tags: python-3.x

Дано число `a(0<a<=1)`. Из чисел 1,1/2,1/3,... . Написать те, которые не меньше `a`.
Округлить до двух десятичных знаков

```
Sample Input 1:
0.33
Sample Output 1:
1
0.5
0.33
```

Comment: @SyntaxError делаете цикл пока 1/i > input и выводите полученное число

Comment: `for i in range(1/a) print 1/i`

Comment: Что Вы сделали сами? Что не получается?

Answer (score 1):

```
massive = [1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2]
#a=float(input()) -Если float вводите значение
#a=int(input()) - Если int вводите значение
a=1 #фиксированное значение a
for i in range(len(massive)):
    if a >= massive[i]:
        print('%.2f'% massive[i])
```

Comment: Вы условия задачи на лету меняете, определитесь что нужно всё-таки